# IndexOutOFBound exception with index 0 size 0 with linked list

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:553)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:474)
    at com.comcast.guide.actionhandlers.MiniGuideActions.checkChannelFocus(MiniGuideActions.java:79)
    at com.comcast.guide.functests.MiniGuideTest.checkChannelFocus(MiniGuideTest.java:34)`
```

I see there is an error here in this line

```
String currentAiringChannelNumber=moduleModel.getGenerators().get(0).getStringParam(TP_CHANNEL_NUMBER)== null ? "" : moduleModel.getGenerators().get(0).getStringParam(TP_CHANNEL_NUMBER);
```

E get method:

```
public E get(int index) {
       checkElementIndex(index);
         return node(index).item;
}
```

checkElementIndex method:

```
private String outOfBoundsMsg(int index) {
     return "Index: "+index+", Size: "+size;
}
private void checkElementIndex(int index) {
    if (!isElementIndex(index))
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
private void checkPositionIndex(int index) {
    if (!isPositionIndex(index))
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```

I am new to Java and I am not able to figure out where exactly should I change the code. Though the test case is executing according
 to the flow it's returning this exception at the end and it's giving
 the exception message at the end. Can someone help me fix it?

Comment: You are trying to access an empty list. Check the error message: You are accessing 0th record with list size 0.

Comment: Please post all of your code.

Comment: Why are you giving us the source code of the `LinkedList` class, which is standard Java, rather than showing us your own code? In the stack trace, you should see where in *your code* the exception was thrown, and then put that code in the question and mark the line where the problem happens. Make sure you show how you fill in the list that is returned by `getGenerators`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your `LinkedList` and make sure it is populated. Below is an example that I broke up into multiple if statements to make it a little more readable.

```
String currentAiringChannelNumber = "";
if (moduleModel.getGenerators() != null && moduleModel.getGenerators().size() > 0) {
    currentAiringChannelNumber = moduleModel.getGenerators().get(0).getStringParam(TP_CHANNEL_NUMBER) == null ? "" : moduleModel.getGenerators().get(0).getStringParam(TP_CHANNEL_NUMBER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means you are trying to access the object at `index` 0 (so the first object), though there is no object in the `LinkedList` (its `size` is 0). So you need to add an object before trying to access it.

You can check if there's any object in the `LinkedList` with `list.size() > 0` before trying to access an object in it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have elements in the "getGenerators()".

You probably will have to validate the existence of the element.

Try something like this

```
String currentAiringChannelNumber=moduleModel.getGenerators().isElementIndex(0) ? "" : moduleModel.getGenerators().get(0).getStringParam(TP_CHANNEL_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems **getGenerator()** is returning an **empty** list in your code. You need to make sure its size should be more than 0 before using get(0) on this list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try-catch as it handles the exception being thrown.

use the following code:

```
    String currentAiringChannelNumber; //Declare String object
    try{ // Following block of code is ran, if an exception is thrown it will be caught and the the lines of code in the try block after the line of code that caused the exception to be thrown will not be run instead the code in the catch block will be ran.
        currentAiringChannelNumber = moduleModel.getGenerators().get(0).getStringParam(TP_CHANNEL_NUMBER);
    }
    catch(Exception e){ //Catching any exception thrown, accommodates for NullPointerException, IndexOutOfBoundsException as well as all other exceptions that are thrown. 
        currentAiringChannelNumber  = ""; //Code to handle predicted exceptions being thrown, which are the NullPointerException and IndexOutOfBoundsException.
    }
```

Note: Code after try-catch statement will be run regardless of whether an exception is thrown while executing code in the try block.